# What is the expectation and variance of a negative binomial distribution NB(r,p)?

Tags: expected-value, negative-binomial

This information can easily be obtained, but the notation that I am using is different. I am looking at the number of trials (k) it takes to obtain r successes, given a certain probability p. This is in contrast to the notation used in Wikipedia, that uses the notation as r failures in k trials.

I also cannot find the information in the textbook.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  "success" and "failure" are purely subjective terms.  If your process has a probability $p$ of success, then it has a $q=1-p$ probability of failure  and you can just, then, look at a process with a probability $q$ of success.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

We can write $X=X_1+\cdots+X_r$ where the $X_i$ are iid having [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter $p$.

Here e.g. $X_i$ counts the number of trials needed to arrive at the first success. Then $X_2$ counts the number of trials (after reaching the first success) needed to arrive at the second success. Et cetera.

Apply linearity of expectation and note that the independence of the $X_i$ also implies linearity when it comes to variance.